# Windows Power Shell script broken

Tags: windows-7

My question is in regard to PShell, the command I was trying to use was .\nvramcheck.ps1, and the response shows something about .\dmp2csv.ps1. The script was working at one time and now it has this error. Anybody know why? or how to fix?

```
The term 'C:\nvramcheck\dmp2csv.ps1' is not recognized as the name of 
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.

At C:\nvramcheck\nvramcheck.ps1:169 char:21
+         $spiDUMP_array = & <<<<  "$script_path\dmp2csv.ps1" $spiDUMP
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\nvramcheck\dmp2csv.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that its trying to access another powershell script `'C:\nvramcheck\dmp2csv.ps1` but it cannot find it, Probably because it doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it.

I'm guessing you copied this script from somewhere and didn't copy the dependant script `'C:\nvramcheck\dmp2csv.ps1`